# Slim PHP: 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

Slim PHP keeps on giving me a 404 Not Found, whenever accessing either the index.php itself, or any of the REST services (e.g. index.php/MyService)

I suspect that my problem is related to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Directory structure:

My Slim index.php is located under

```
/var/www/api/v1/index.php
```

My apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I can execute any other PHP script just fine (e.g. /api/v1/test.php)

Comment: Try to remove your `.htaccess` file and check if the `index.php` file works.

Comment: Already did that - but no luck. Navigating to /api/v1/index.php gives me a 404 as well. However, in the same directory I placed a test.php file, which works just fine

Comment: Are your permissions to `index.php` ok?

Comment: Show also the contents of index.php file.

Comment: @DavidePastore: Yes, the permissions are fine:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  for index.php (and all other files)

I had changed it to 777 for testing

Comment: @MikaTuupola: I'm not sure the contents is the problem - it runs fine locally.

Comment: Hmmm, try to config `.htaccess` in the same place where is your index.php,

`RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]` if that not working I think its problem with main `.htaccess` file

Comment: Depending on your version of apache you might need to remove the Require all granted.